# "fetch" is undefined and "localStorage" is undefined , on using eslint-config-airbnb in react.js

Tags: reactjs, eslint-config-airbnb

I want to modify my code structure using eslint of airbnb. I have follwed these instruction given in [eslint-config-airbnb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb). After initiating the command 
`npm run lint`, results consists of `'fetch' is not defined` and also, `'localStorage' is not defined`.

I have gone through this [github issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4015), but still error is shown as the same `'fetch is not defined'`. Is there any solutions for it.

Comment: please edit your question and show us your eslint config file

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can configure your `.eslintrc` file with `globals`.

Add this to your `.eslintrc` file.

```
"globals": {
        "localStorage": true,
        "fetch": true
    }
```

Comment: gr8, happy linting! if you get annoyed or you have lots of global variable in use. then just put. `"no-undef": 0` inside `rules` tag of .eslintrc file.

Answer (score 41):

No need to add it as an exception, just add this to your `.eslintrc` and `eslint` will know what it is:

```
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  }
```

Comment: I had this already set but `localStorage` was still not recognized.

Comment: It works! You're right, no need to add it as an exception 

Comment: adding `browser: true` will result in other errors such as not being able to recognize Node.js specifics i.e. `process.env`

Comment: the accepted answer seems to be more targetted at the issue. setting `browser: true` will cause many other linting errors to disappear such as unused variables.

Answer (score 5):

you can try to access to the `fetch` and `localStorage` through `window` object.

`window.fetch`, `window.localStorage`

Comment: This works as a solution when trying to abide by lint rules w/o needing to modify the config. This is the case if you use a tool like StandardJS: https://standardjs.com/

Comment: 'localStorage' is not defined. (no-undef) standard(no-undef) 
That is exactly what I was trying to remedy.  Thank you!